# How can I access the Template References of my ViewChildren?

Tags: angular

Consider these material tabs in my template:

```
<mat-tab #myFirstTab>Something</mat-tab>
<mat-tab #mySecondTab>Something else</mat-tab>
```

And the ViewChildren in the .ts file:

```
  @ViewChildren(MatTab)
  private allTabs: QueryList<MatTab>;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.allTabs.forEach(tab => console.log('tab: ', tab));
  }
```

How can I access the **actual template references of each tab** (#myFirstTab and #mySecondTab) in my .ts code ? Is it possible at all this way around ? I need a way to **differentiate my tabs**, and the label text is not good because it can vary...

**Edit:** I specifically asked for @ViewChildren and not @ViewChild. Of course I know the other way around. In this case, **I do not want to have to declare each Viewchild in my .ts file**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select an element in a component template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template)

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish by avoiding the `ViewChild` directive. It seems like you either need something like (imaginary) `const myFirstTab = allTabs.find(tab => tab.templateRefName === 'myFirstTab');` or `@ViewChild('myFirstTab') myFirstTab: MatTab;`. The second approach is both shorter and more idiomatic in Angular (and also exists).

Comment: I am trying to avoid code duplication and boiler plate code. I want to be able to add another Mat Tab without having to add a new explicit ViewChild.

Answer (score 0):

[ViewChild directive](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)? e.g.

```js
@ViewChild('myFirstTab') myFirstTab: MatTab;
@ViewChild('mySecondTab') mySecondTab: MatTab;
```

Comment: I specifically asked for ViewChildren and not ViewChild. Of course I know the other way around. In this case, **I do not want to have to declare each Viewchild in my .ts file